# When to call CloseTouchInputHandle

Tags: winapi, vb6

I'm calling GetTouchInputInfo like this:

```
RetVal = GetTouchInputInfo(hTouchInput, TouchPoints, tiTouchInput(1&), LenB(tiTouchInput(1&)))
```

I wonder when I should call

```
CloseTouchInputHandle
```

Should every GetTouchInputInfo be followed by CloseTouchInputHandle?

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-closetouchinputhandle) do not explain when / why to call CloseTouchInput.

I'm asking because I have seen examples where people call it only in situations like this:

```
   'Check for TouchDown and process it
    If tiTouchInput(i).dwFlags And TOUCHEVENTF_DOWN Then
        OnTouch = True
        m_blnSkipNextMouseDown = True
        hTouchInput = CloseTouchInputHandle(hTouchInput):   Debug.Assert hTouchInput
```

(The above sample seems to have been done by a newbie anyways because hTouchInput is not altered by CloseTouchInput)

Or in situations where TOUCHEVENT_UP occurs.

These implementations don't make sense to me, that's why I ask here.

The code that I'm referring to is this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const SM_DIGITIZER As Long = 94
Private Const WM_TOUCH     As Long = &H240

Private Enum RegisterTouchWindowFlags
    TWF_FINETOUCH = &H1
    TWF_WANTPALM = &H2
End Enum
#If False Then
    Dim TWF_FINETOUCH, TWF_WANTPALM
#End If

Private Enum DigitizerConstants
    TABLET_CONFIG_NONE = &H0
    NID_INTEGRATED_TOUCH = &H1
    NID_EXTERNAL_TOUCH = &H2
    NID_INTEGRATED_PEN = &H4
    NID_EXTERNAL_PEN = &H8
    NID_MULTI_INPUT = &H40
    NID_READY = &H80
End Enum
#If False Then
    Dim TABLET_CONFIG_NONE, NID_INTEGRATED_TOUCH, NID_EXTERNAL_TOUCH, _
    NID_INTEGRATED_PEN, NID_EXTERNAL_PEN, NID_MULTI_INPUT, NID_READY
#End If

Private Enum TOUCHINPUT_Flags
    TOUCHEVENTF_MOVE = &H1
    TOUCHEVENTF_DOWN = &H2
    TOUCHEVENTF_UP = &H4
    TOUCHEVENTF_INRANGE = &H8
    TOUCHEVENTF_PRIMARY = &H10
    TOUCHEVENTF_NOCOALESCE = &H20
    TOUCHEVENTF_PALM = &H80
End Enum
#If False Then
    Dim TOUCHEVENTF_MOVE, TOUCHEVENTF_DOWN, TOUCHEVENTF_UP, TOUCHEVENTF_INRANGE, _
    TOUCHEVENTF_PRIMARY, TOUCHEVENTF_NOCOALESCE, TOUCHEVENTF_PALM
#End If

Private Enum TOUCHINPUT_Masks
    TOUCHINPUTMASKF_TIMEFROMSYSTEM = &H1
    TOUCHINPUTMASKF_EXTRAINFO = &H2
    TOUCHINPUTMASKF_CONTACTAREA = &H4
End Enum
#If False Then
    Dim TOUCHINPUTMASKF_TIMEFROMSYSTEM, TOUCHINPUTMASKF_EXTRAINFO, TOUCHINPUTMASKF_CONTACTAREA
#End If

Private Type TOUCHINPUT
    X           As Long
    Y           As Long
    hSource     As Long
    dwID        As Long
    dwFlags     As TOUCHINPUT_Flags
    dwMask      As TOUCHINPUT_Masks
    dwTime      As Long
    dwExtraInfo As Long
    cxContact   As Long
    cyContact   As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function CloseTouchInputHandle Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hTouchInput As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetTouchInputInfo Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hTouchInput As Long, ByVal cInputs As Long, ByRef pInputs As TOUCHINPUT, ByVal cbSize As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RegisterTouchWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long, Optional ByVal ulFlags As RegisterTouchWindowFlags) As Long

Private Declare Function DefSubclassProc Lib "comctl32.dll" Alias "#413" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowSubclass Lib "comctl32.dll" Alias "#410" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal pfnSubclass As Long, ByVal uIdSubclass As Long, Optional ByVal dwRefData As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RemoveWindowSubclass Lib "comctl32.dll" Alias "#412" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal pfnSubclass As Long, ByVal uIdSubclass As Long) As Long

Private m_blnSkipNextMouseDown As Boolean
Private m_strMessageOld        As String

Private Sub cmdTouch_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    tmrDown = True
    lblDown.BackColor = vbCyan
End Sub                                 'Error handling isn't really necessary in these 2 Subs

Private Sub cmdTouch_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    tmrUp = True
    lblUp.BackColor = vbCyan
End Sub                                 'because the values being assigned won't ever trigger an error

Private Sub Form_Load() 'Accessing any of a Form's property or control loads it, so might as well run the following code in the proper event
    Dim IsIntegratedTouch As Boolean, IsStackReady As Boolean, hWndBtn As Long

    lblDown = vbNewLine & lblDown
    lblUp = vbNewLine & lblUp

   'Retrieve digitizer status & capabilities
    hWndBtn = GetSystemMetrics(SM_DIGITIZER)
    IsIntegratedTouch = (hWndBtn And NID_INTEGRATED_TOUCH) = NID_INTEGRATED_TOUCH
    IsStackReady = (hWndBtn And NID_READY) = NID_READY

    txtDbgMsg = "Integrated Touch = " & IIf$(IsIntegratedTouch, "True", "False") & vbNewLine _
              & "Stack Ready = " & IIf$(IsStackReady, "True", "False") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

   'See if we need to use touch events
    If IsStackReady And IsIntegratedTouch Then
        hWndBtn = cmdTouch.hWnd

       'Register button to receive touch events and substitute window event handling procedure
        If RegisterTouchWindow(hWndBtn) Then
            hWndBtn = SetWindowSubclass(hWndBtn, AddressOf StaticSubclassProc, ObjPtr(Me)): Debug.Assert hWndBtn
        End If
    End If
End Sub                                 'Error handling is useless in this Sub because VB6 is unable to catch errors thrown by APIs

Private Sub Form_Resize()
    Dim txtDbgMsg_Left As Single, txtDbgMsg_Top As Single

    txtDbgMsg_Left = txtDbgMsg.Left
    txtDbgMsg_Top = txtDbgMsg.Top

    On Error Resume Next
    txtDbgMsg.Move txtDbgMsg_Left, txtDbgMsg_Top, ScaleWidth - txtDbgMsg_Left - 150!, ScaleHeight - txtDbgMsg_Top - 150!
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    RemoveWindowSubclass cmdTouch.hWnd, AddressOf StaticSubclassProc, ObjPtr(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub tmrDown_Timer()
    tmrDown = False
    lblDown.BackColor = vbButtonFace
End Sub                                 'Error handling is also unnecessary in these 2 Subs

Private Sub tmrUp_Timer()
    tmrUp = False
    lblUp.BackColor = vbButtonFace
End Sub                                 'because the values being assigned won't ever trigger an error

'Replacement for VBA.IIf() that is optimized for Strings
Private Function IIf$(ByVal Expression As Boolean, ByRef TruePart As String, ByRef FalsePart As String)
    If Expression Then IIf$ = TruePart Else IIf$ = FalsePart
End Function

Private Function OnTouch(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal TouchPoints As Long, ByVal hTouchInput As Long) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, RetVal As Long, strMessage As String, tiTouchInput() As TOUCHINPUT

    ReDim tiTouchInput(1& To TouchPoints) As TOUCHINPUT 'Allocate the TOUCHINPUT array

    RetVal = GetTouchInputInfo(hTouchInput, TouchPoints, tiTouchInput(1&), LenB(tiTouchInput(1&)))

   'Loop through TOUCHINPUT structures
    For i = 1& To TouchPoints
        strMessage = "ID=" & tiTouchInput(i).dwID & _
                   ", hSource=&H" & Hex$(tiTouchInput(i).hSource) & _
                   ", dwFlags=&H" & Hex$(tiTouchInput(i).dwFlags) & _
                   ", RetVal=" & RetVal & _
                   ", hWnd=&H" & Hex$(hWnd) & _
                   ", TouchPoints=" & TouchPoints & vbNewLine

       'Display diagnostic information
        If StrComp(strMessage, m_strMessageOld) Then    'StrComp() is actually faster than either the = or <> operators
            On Error Resume Next
            txtDbgMsg.SelStart = &HFFFF&                'Appending text via .SelText is quicker than retrieving the
            txtDbgMsg.SelText = strMessage              'entire .Text contents and concatenating it with additional text
            On Error GoTo 0
            m_strMessageOld = strMessage
        End If

       'Check for TouchDown and process it
        If tiTouchInput(i).dwFlags And TOUCHEVENTF_DOWN Then
            OnTouch = True
            m_blnSkipNextMouseDown = True
            hTouchInput = CloseTouchInputHandle(hTouchInput):   Debug.Assert hTouchInput
            tmrDown = True
            lblDown.BackColor = vbCyan
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Friend Function SubclassProc(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long, ByVal dwRefData As Long) As Long
    If uMsg = WM_TOUCH Then If OnTouch(hWnd, wParam And &HFFFF&, lParam) Then Exit Function

    SubclassProc = DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam) 'Avoid declaring additional variables inside window/subclass procedures because they'll still
End Function                                                   'be allocated even for messages not being handled there. Create a separate procedure instead.
```

Comment: If nothing else, `hTouchInput = CloseTouchInputHandle(hTouchInput)` is wrong to assign the return value back to `hTouchInput`, since `CloseTouchInputHandle()` returns a `BOOL` not `HTOUCHINPUT`.

Answer (score 4):

Per the `WM_TOUCH` documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/wm-touchdown

> *lParam*
>
> Contains a touch input handle that can be used in a call to [GetTouchInputInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-gettouchinputinfo) to retrieve detailed information about the touch points associated with this message.
>
> This handle is valid only within the current process and should not be passed cross-process except as the LPARAM in a SendMessage or PostMessage call.
>
> **When the application no longer requires this handle, the application must call CloseTouchInputHandle to free the process memory associated with this handle. Failing to do so can result in an application memory leak.**
>
> **Note that the touch input handle in this parameter is no longer valid after the message has been passed to [DefWindowProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-defwindowproca). [DefWindowProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-defwindowproca) will close and invalidate this handle.**
>
> Note also that the touch input handle in this parameter is no longer valid after the message has been forwarded using [PostMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/sendmessage--postmessage--and-related-functions), SendMessage, or one of their variants. These functions will close and invalidate this handle.

In the example you provided, it is not calling `DefSubclassProc()` (which will call `DefWindowProc()`) if `OnTouch()` returns `True`, so `OnTouch()` calls `CloseTouchInputHandle()` before returning `True` (which is a bit redundant in this example).

Comment: Do you see why he exits SubclassProc if OnTouch is true?

Comment: @tmighty The example is preventing the window from default-processing any `WM_TOUCH(TOUCHEVENTF_DOWN)` events. You would have to ask the author about WHY he is doing that.

Comment: Do you think it's to prevent having the usual WM_CLICK or what its called after WM_TOUCH?

Comment: @tmighty I'd rather not speculate on why it does what it is doing